# mysql connection not working? - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database. That's it... But i can't manage to make it work...
My code is separated in two files WebServer.js where i just listen for request and db.js where i put a class that manage the database.

So here's my code:

- db.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = class db {
    constructor(host, user, pass, database){
        this.db = mysql.createConnection({
            host: host,
            user: user,
            password: pass,
            database: database,
        });
        this.db.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
           
            console.log('DB connection successful as id ' + connection.threadId);
        });
    }
}
```

- WebServer.js (Only the part that touch the db.js):

```
const db = require("./db");
////
var mdb = new db('localhost', "GarageHelper", "GarageHelper", "Garage Helper");
```

I'm getting this error:

```
/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

ReferenceError: connection is not defined
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/db.js:16:61)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/DisqueExterne/Codes source/iut/GarageHelper/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
```

I have NodeJS v12.19.0 (try on v17.3.0 on an other machine (i changed the host to the ip of the db) but same error)
mysql was installed using npm install mysql with npm v8.3.0
I searched for hours the issue but i don't see how i'm doing somthing wrong with this little of code...
The error seems to come from the mysql lib but how the lib could be broken?
Maybe i missing something.
Anyway, i'm desperate... Thanks for any help...

Comment: i think the problem is with `connection.threadId` inside `console.log`, change it to `this.db.threadId` since it's your mysql connection

Comment: @sinabariaji, You're right ^^ I'm feeling dumb right now... I should stop programming when i'm tired ^^ What confused me is that i didn't read the stacktrace correctly and i thought it was inside mysql... Thanks for pointing out my mistake! Have a great day!